# Hello. I would like to ask a question about usage of "My House"

Tags: word-usage

I'm Korean. Of course English is not my second language. It's more like Foreign language.

I've seen somebody saying that IF I want to us the expression of 'My House', I have to actually possess (own) the house as my asset.

For example, "welcome to my house" or "come to my house this weekend."

Is it true??

If I'm living in a place that I don't have as my real estate, can I use those expressions?

Answer (score 4):

At least in the US, "my house" can most certainly be used to refer to the house you live in, regardless of ownership status.

Comment: So, I'm paying rent money for living in there, I can still say "come to my house" as well..  Good Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In English, the adjective "my" can refer to an association or ownership *( possession )*
For example:

*"I love my country."* You do not **own** the country, but are associated with it.
*"I will donate my kidney."* You **own** the kidney.